# IIS Smooth Streaming Manifest Bad Request Error

Tags: iis, streaming, manifest, smoothing

I installed IIS Media Services 3.0, and the Big Buck Bunny sample, but when I try to get the manifest file (http://localhost/Big_Buck_Bunny/Big Buck Bunny.ism/Manifest), I get 400.0 Bad Request error from the SmoothHandler. So the default.html appears in the browser, but the SL player shows error while trying to read the manifest. Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. An URL Rewrite rule changed the requested URL.